# How to unit test promise with sinon in my case?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I am trying to start a stub in unit test for my app.

I have something like this in my file.

```
var sinon = require('sinon'),
    should = require('should');

require('sinon-stub-promise');

describe('test unit Tests', function(){
    describe('My first test', function(){
        it('should test a promise', function(){
            sinon.stub().resolves('foo')().then(function (value) {
            console.log('test');

            assert.equal(value, 'not foooo')
        })
    })
});
```

My problem is I can't seem to trigger the `assert.equal error`. I can see the '`test`' in the output when run the test. However, the test should fail because the value should be `foo` and not '`not foooo`'. For some reason it passed. I am not sure the reason. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to return the promise so mocha waits:

```
describe('test unit Tests', function(){
    describe('My first test', function(){
        it('should test a promise', function(){
            return sinon.stub().resolves('foo')().then(function (value) {
              console.log('test');

              assert.equal(value, 'not foooo')
            })
        })
    })
});
```